# Virtual Filesystem that hides file location and moves items around

Tags: linux, filesystems, nas, fuse

I have a media box and a NAS. At the moment I would like to have most of the videos that I would like to watch on the media box. [For performance reasons] All of the other videos I would like to storage on the NAS. Is there a FUSE component that will allow for me to setup time-based rules on what is stored on the local machine, and what gets archived on the NAS?

For example: Let's say I have the latest videos downloaded via `iTunes/mediaprovider`. For all of the new files, I would like for them to be stored locally. If there are any files still there after X time, I would like for them to get stored on the NAS.

What I'm looking for is a way to have the appearance that both sources are merged and have some sort of rule that sweeps stuff away.

Comment: The term for this is a [Clustered File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_disk_file_system), but I don't know of any consumer products that do this. I would be interested in the answer to this. +1 and favorited :)

Comment: Unless there is a better solution, I'm nearly to the point of doing an SSHFS+merge FUSE FS and do a cron to roll over the files in the local directory

Answer (score 1):

Although not being a file system, [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) might be the solution for your problem. With git annex, you can store binary files and track their locations. You can easily copy to other remotes or remove files locally.